# Declaration of set container with variable string

Tags: c++, set

I have this question. Is it possible to declare more set "groups" just with one `set<string>name` where the "name" will be string, which will change with each rotation of while cycle? I mean something like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    set<string> setname;
    string example = "This is an example of string";
    string s;
    istringstream f(example);
    while (getline(f, s, ' ')){
        set<string>s;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

The question is whether the sets will remain declarated even after another rotation of while-cycle, whether `set<string>This` will be declarated even after "s" will be string "is". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop

```
while (getline(f, s, ' ')){
    set<string>s;
    }
```

object s of type `std::set<std::string>` will be created anew in each iteration of the loop because it is a local variable of the compound statement of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is whether the sets will remain declarated even after another rotation of while-cycle

1. You are actually shadowing the declaration of `string s;` with `set<string>s;` inside the while loop. They are unrelated!
2. Yes, the `set<string>s;` will create a new instance of the set for every cycle of the `while` loop.